# Jupyter notebook command returns Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, jupyter

I have been following along the Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow book. I have followed all commands but every time I try to run `$jupyter notebook`
I receive the following error:

> "Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Here is a list of all the commands I have run so far:

```
$sudo apt-get install python-setuptools

$sudo easy_install pip==9.0.1

$sudo pip install virtualenv

$pip3 install --user --upgrade virtualenv

$source env/bin/activate

$pip3 install --upgrade jupyter matplotlib numpy pandas scipy scikit-learn

$sudo pip install jupyter

$pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter

$pip install notebook
```

As you can see, I have tried a lot and it still won't work. I am using windows 10 with an ubuntu shell (bash). I have also installed anaconda but it is in my D: drive, not the C: drive. Could that be it? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: I have reinstalled anaconda on my C drive and restarted my computer but it still won't work.

Comment: What happens when you run `jupyter-notebook` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue. This is what I did to fix the issue (on Ubuntu 16.04) :

`sudo apt-get remove ipython`

`sudo apt-get purge ipython`

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

`pip install jupyter` ( or pip3 depending on python version)

ipython seemed to be the problem, hence removing it fixed the issue.

I'm now able to run `jupyter notebook`